# Django evert migration on custom migration

Tags: django, django-migrations

I'm currently struggling with custom Django migrations and more specifically with the ability to revert it.

I have a model UserSubscription with a foreign key 'Subscription' that represent a subscription with price, name, type, etc.
UserSubscription keep track of every event occuring with our payment service (last payment, errors, date of sub, etc...)

My migration remove this Subscription foreign key and add a new one UserConditionalOffer (that track a sub with promotion or special offers)

playing the migration forwards works well, but when I play it backwards, I need to remove UserConditionalOffer and recreate the Subscription foreign key with a default value.

As I understand it, Django will do those operations but cannot repopulate the table with subscription values.

UserSubscription model :

```
class UserSubscription(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name = 'user', null = False, blank = False)
user_conditional_offer = models.ForeignKey(UserConditionalOffer, verbose_name = 'user conditional offer', null = False, blank = False)
...
# removed line : subscription = models.ForeignKey(Subscription, verbose_name = 'subscription', null = False, blank = False)
```

As you can see, Subscription cannot be null. So when Django revert this migration, it creates a field subscription in UserSubscription, but leave it null, and fails.

I just need to set subscription to 1 (the default subscription)

I tried to use migrations.RunSQL with reverse_sql but I get :

```
cannot ALTER TABLE "vadom_billing_user_subscription" because it has pending trigger events
```

It appears that I cannot update the table and then alter the table schema in one migration.

Do you guys have a solution to this ?

Thanks